# How can I make sure I buy a SATA-USB adapter compatible with my harddrive?

Tags: sata, compatibility, adapter

I'm planning on removing the hard drive from a laptop and connecting it to another computer via a USB adapter. I understand I need a SATA-USB adapter, but I don't want to buy one that isn't compatible with my harddrive. Is that possible? If so, what information do I need to make sure I get a compatible adapter?

Comment: what comparability are you worried about?  One end of your cable will be sata and the other will be usb.  these are both standardized connectors

Comment: The only time where I have been burned on SATA is at boot-time with XP and had to integrate a SATA Driver into the ISO using WinLite.

Comment: @RussellUhl What I'm saying is, I don't know anything about SATA. As far as I know there could be five different variants of it, or subtle technical differences that I'm not aware of.

Comment: ah ok.  You don't have to worry about that.  There's SATA I, II, and III, but those are all bus speeds on the motherboard (which you won't be utilizing, because you're using USB).  They all use the same physical connector.  Having said that, on the USB end of things, try to go with USB 3 (assuming your computer has USB 3), since that will probably work faster for you.

Comment: @RussellUhl What about 2.5 inch versus 3.5 inch? I've heard 2.5 inch adapters won't work with 3.5 because of power issues. I also see pin counts (7, 15, 22) on adapters, is that important?

Comment: 2.5 vs 3.5 are drive sizes, not connectors.  you're WAY overthinking this.

Answer (score 1):

USB and SATA are well defined standards. If a particular adapter you buy is not fit for this purpose then any merchant should accept it back for a full refund.